# Make the rate table for relative survival analysis

Tags: r

The package "relsurv" can calculate relative survival.

Input are your data (in my case patients diagnosed with colorectal cancer) and then the rate table which includes the change of surviving to the next age category, generally split by sex and year of diagnosis.

In my case, I want to have relative survival according to age, sex, year of diagnosis and socio-economic score. I have all the data that should go into the rate table in 1 data frame:

```
   > head(lifetable)
     sex  seifa age      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013
1 female SEIFA1   0 0.9947100 0.9953400 0.9956200 0.9959200 0.9964100 0.9966000 0.9966800
2 female SEIFA1   1 0.9996625 0.9996613 0.9997038 0.9996489 0.9996425 0.9996667 0.9997556
3 female SEIFA1   2 0.9997750 0.9997968 0.9998105 0.9998119 0.9998350 0.9998167 0.9998656
4 female SEIFA1   3 0.9998375 0.9998374 0.9998460 0.9998621 0.9998625 0.9998667 0.9999022
5 female SEIFA1   4 0.9998750 0.9998645 0.9998697 0.9998871 0.9998900 0.9999000 0.9999267
6 female SEIFA1   5 0.9998827 0.9999077 0.9998887 0.9998956 0.9999037 0.9999160 0.9999280
```

I am looking for a quick and easy way to transform this into the 'ratetable'. I searched a lot but found nothing... Anyone?

Comment: You want to " transform this into the 'ratetable'". What 'ratetable' would that be? The whole idea of relative survival is inconsistent with the notion of rate-tables. It is using a measure that is not based on rates of events but rather on rates of non-events. Well, not _exactly_ rates of non-events but rather some sort of ratio of the prevalence of non-events in two different groups. I've always found it to be a confused measure of risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close this topic, I found a solution:

1. Create 5 standard rate tables (by age,sex,year), one for each seifa category.

> ```
>    for (i in seq_along(levels(lifetable$seifa))){         # Create standard ratetables (by age,sex,year) for each seifa category
>    lt_ss_f <- subset(lifetable, seifa == paste("SEIFA", i, sep="") & sex =="female"); lt_ss_f <- lt_ss_f[-c(1:3)]; lt_ss_f <- as.matrix(lt_ss_f)    
>    lt_ss_m <- subset(lifetable, seifa == paste("SEIFA", i, sep="") & sex =="male")  ; lt_ss_m <- lt_ss_m[-c(1:3)]; lt_ss_m <- as.matrix(lt_ss_m)     
>    assign(paste("SEIFA", i, sep=""),  transrate(lt_ss_m,lt_ss_f, yearlim=c(2003,2013), int.length=1))}
> ```

2. Join the 5 rate tables using joinrate() to create the full rate table, which now includes the 4th dimension (age, sex, year & seifa).

> ```
> FULLrateTable <- joinrate(list(SEIFA1=SEIFA1, SEIFA2=SEIFA2, SEIFA3=SEIFA3, SEIFA4=SEIFA4, SEIFA5=SEIFA5),dim.name="SEIFA")
> ```